# Status of fixed-size parameter packs

Tags: c++, standards, c++14

I am currently curious about the progression of the Fixed Size Parameter Packs C++ language feature proposal ([n4072](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4072.html)). This feature allows for the following to be valid C++ syntax:

```
void Foo( int...[10] iList );
```

This would allow for various useful template metaprogramming features. My main reason for intrigue is because I am creating a library class which represents a mathematical Tensor object with arbitrary rank.

This would allow me to do the following when indexing the class:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
class CTensor {
      // ...
public:
     NumType& operator()( std::size_t...[sizeof...(Sizes)] coords ) 
     {
          // Return reference to element at the position specified
          // by coords.
     }
};
```

And call it in the following way:

```
CTensor<int, 3, 4, 5> tensor;
/* tensor( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) = 5; // Results in a descriptive compile-time error */
tensor( 1, 2, 3 ) = 5; // Sets the element at (1, 2, 3) to 5.
```

To my knowledge there is no way to achieve this in standard C++11, so I am very interested in this proposal, but I cannot find any information as to it's acceptance or rejection by the working group; can anyone provide more information?

Comment: See [this Rapperswil trip report](http://botondballo.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/trip-report-c-standards-committee-meeting-in-rapperswil-june-2014/). Anyway, it's possible in C++ with a static assertion that the sizes are the same or SFINAEing it out if they aren't.

Comment: There isn't really a deadly urgency for this. You can already write code that does what you want, it's just a little bit more verbose.

Comment: Plus, with concepts-lite, the code that does what you want is far easier to write.  Which also makes it far easier to specify what `...[X]` means, because then they can lean on concepts.

Answer (score 6):

What you have asked for can be achieved in standard C++.  It will be even easier to do once concepts enters the language.

Here is an implementation in standard C++:

```
template<std::size_t N, class...Ts>
constexpr bool exactly_N_types() {
  return sizeof...(Ts) == N;
}
template<bool b,class T=void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
template<class T0>
constexpr bool can_all_convert_to { return true; }

template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
constexpr bool can_all_convert_to() {
  return std::is_convertible< T1, T0 >::value && can_all_convert_to<T0, Ts...>();
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
struct CTensor {
  template<class... sizes>
  enable_if_t<
    exactly_N_types< sizeof...(Sizes), sizes...>()
    && can_all_convert_to< std::size_t, sizes...>()
    ,NumType&
  >
  operator()( sizes... coords ) 
  {
      // Return reference to element at the position specified
      // by coords.
  }
};
```

It is overly verbose.  I could replace `exactly_N_types<?,?>` with `sizeof...(Sizes)==sizeof...(sizes)`, which would reduce the bulk, but I decided to do it in a pseudo-concepts way.

Once we have concepts, specifying what `...[N]` means will matter less (because the bulk of the above gets simplified), and it will also become easier to specify what it means.  Both are reasons to defer `...[N]` until after concepts are in the language.  (On the other hand, the same is true of a lot, and the last time we might have been tempted to defer features for concepts it would have been a mistake!)

With concepts lite, it will look something like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... s>
struct CTensor {
  template<Sizes... sizes> requires exactly_N_types<sizeof...(s), Sizes...>
  NumType& operator()( sizes... coords ) 
  {
      // Return reference to element at the position specified
      // by coords.
  }
};
```

or somesuch.

Answer (score 4):

Mara Bos presented a preliminary draft of it at Rapperswil to the evolution group, and a vote was taken to strongly encourage her to keep working on it.  She then formally submitted N4072 in the Post-Rapperswil mailing, which means it is scheduled to be presented by her again at Urbana in October.  As it is a core change, if it passes it will be part of C++17, or whatever the next version of C++ is after C++14.

Comment: Do you know if there has been an update to this? Afaik it didn't make it into c++17 and I couldn't find any mention of a follow up proposal at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific case can be solved by crafting a pack expansion over a pattern depending on `Sizes` but producing `std::size_t`. The following will do:

```
template <class T, std::size_t>
using depend_v = T;

// ...

T& operator()( depend_v<std::size_t, Sizes>... coords ) { /* ... */ }
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zN0w7uo71FHYTEiU)